# Not all sites login automatically using CAS?

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, cas, autologin

I already have a working CAS and other sites has the capability to for single sign on. But there is this one site, that does not login automatically. It redirects me to the sites login page though I have successfully signed on in CAS.

Is it possible that SSO do not work on other sites? And why is that? What are the requirements so that SSO will work on that site?

Answer (score 1):

SSO works for all other service site. The above scenario. that you described is only happen if you passed `renew=true` parameter with you `serviceUrl`.

For example: your request url to CAS server look like this

https://www.yourcasserver.com/cas/login?service=http://youwebapp.com&renew=true

In this case, parameter `renew=true`, It allows a client to advise the CAS server login to always authenticate a user regardless of whether a single sign on session already exists.

And this is the useful feature of CAS server, because certain services that would like to use CAS as the authentication mechanism but allow access to sensitive material. They can force CAS to reauthenticate a user to ensure that they are signing in the correct user (and its not a pre-existing SSO session that wasn't terminated.

To use CAS SSO service for all client application, you have to set "renew=false" parameter or you have not pass any renew parameter to CAS login page URL.